# Waiting for Google Geocoder results in a jquery custom validation method

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-validate, google-geocoding-api

I know Google's Geocoder service is asynchronous, but I need a way to return true or false to my custom jQuery Validate method after the google geocoder results have returned and not before. (ex. the service will look up a zip code, if found return true, else return false).

Edit - Is jQuery Validate `remote` method the way to do it?

Currently I have a set of rules for the element, but when I test this code below the `getLocation` method gets called as soon as the code is loaded, not when a 5th digit is entered like I want.

```js
$('#Location').rules("add", {
  required: true,
  minlength: 5,
  maxlength: 5,
  messages: {
    required: "Required input",
    minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, {0} characters are necessary"),
    maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, {0} characters are necessary")
  },
  remote: getLocation()
});

function getLocation() {
  var i = 0;
}
```

Here is my custom method.

```js
 $.validator.addMethod("validateZipCode", function(value, element) {
   var isValidZipCode = GetGoogleGeocoderResultsByZip(value);
   return zipCodeIsValid;
 }, "Invalid location");


 //the geocode results work something like this, but I need to wait to return true/false
 function GetGoogleGeocoderResultsByZip(zipCode) {
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     geocoder.geocode("componentRestrictions": {
         "country": "United States",
         "postalCode": zipCode
       }, function(results, status) {
         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
           if (results.length >= 1) {
             return true;
           }
           return false;
         }
       }
     };
```

Comment: "Code snippets" are for running the JavaScript code within this page.  Since you cannot run your code on this page, I've removed the snippet.

Comment: If you only want to run validation after the 5th digit is entered, you'll have to alter the way validation is triggered.  Try setting `onkeyup` to `false`... then validation will only get triggered on the `focusout` and `submit` events.  If you want to restrict this behavior to one field, then you'll need to write a custom function for `onkeyup` that contains a conditional. [See plugin options](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).

Comment: do you know where I can find an example of a custom function for onkeyup?

Comment: You could look at the function in the source code of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

[As I mentioned in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879293/waiting-for-google-geocoder-results-in-a-jquery-custom-validation-method#comment59427492_35879293), pull the default `onkeyup` function [from the plugin](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js) and modify it for your over-ride.

```
$("#contact").validate({
    onkeyup: function(element, event) {
        if (element.name == "zip-code") {
            return; // no onkeyup validation at all
        } else {
            // default onkeyup validation in here
            var excludedKeys = [
                16, 17, 18, 20, 35, 36, 37,
                38, 39, 40, 45, 144, 225
            ];
            if ( event.which === 9 && this.elementValue( element ) === "" || $.inArray( event.keyCode, excludedKeys ) !== -1 ) {
                return;
            } else if ( element.name in this.submitted || element.name in this.invalid ) {
                this.element( element );
            }
        }
    },
    ....
```

In the proof-of-concept DEMO below, hit the `submit` button to first get past the "lazy" validation, then compare the behavior of the two fields.  The first field is validating for an email address on every `keyup` event.  The second field is not validating for email on `keyup` events at all, only on `focusout` and `submit`.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/vbcpyv3q/**